# Creating a custom widget with other widgets included

Tags: android, widget, code-reuse, reusability

I am fairly new to android development and I am having a hard time figuring out the simplest way to create reusable code. I have found quite a few articles on google, android has a lot of parts and solutions I am having trouble seeing the pros and cons, so I will just post what I would like to do, then see what pops up.

Currently I have:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/widget_toolbar"/>

        <ListView
            android:background="@color/amber_A700"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <apps.new.app.ui.widget.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:insetForeground="#4000" >

        <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.example.newapp.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/frag_nav_drawer" />

    </apps.new.app.ui.widget.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Essentially what I want is to make this a library in which I could use in any project I want with a more simplistic style:

```
<android.my.custom.widget
    ...
    app:drawerFragment="drawer_fragment_name"
    ...>

    //Listview would go here

</android.my.custom.widget>
```

This would allow me to set the drawer fragment, include the "ScrimInsetsFrameLayout" automatically, include the toolbar automatically. Essentially I want a reusable library in which I could update and it would push to any app I use it in. What is the best practice with android dev? If this is simply a custom widget, how would I go about including other widgets in it and inserting fragments in them?

ultimately this would allow me to simplify the code a bunch and only see what is for this activity instead of seeing a bunch of boiler-plate code for the navigation drawer, RelativeLayout and toolbar.

I feel like I am just missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new class which inherits from `DrawerLayout`, inflate your views, set params.

Tutorial is [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_components.htm)